# Applying margin on <div1>

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I was asked in one of my interviews that "There are two divs, div1 and div2  if we apply 100 margin on div1 what will be the result and how it will effect both divs?".. i have searched this answer on internet but didn't get the exact answer..

Comment: depends on a lot. How do they add margin to it? If they only add margin to `div1`,  `div2` will be 100px?. lower on the page. The result would be in that case, that a margin (white space) of `100` will be added on top, right, bottom, left of the `div1`. IF they only specify 100 I would say nothing as you have to define px for instance.

Comment: Be aware of `margin-collapse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide the unit of margin measure, I assume `px`. If we're talking about two `div` elements **without any additional styling** (important), so that their `display` property value is `block`, the first `div` will simply get margin 100, while the other will be visually moved, since the first' `div` margin will take some space that will push the second one down. If those elements have any content, the first' `div` content will be shifted by 100 (to the right) from the other's content.

```css
#div1 {
  margin:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id='div1'>This is the first div</div>
<div id='div2'>This is the second div</div>
```

Comment: If they did really ask it this way, then I wouldn't assume `px` and would say that nothing happens as no unit is specified. And if they then say it's wrong I would run away quickly.

Answer (score 3):

In simple way, if your div contains any content then your div with margin move as shown in below snippet.div with margin have 100px margin on all four sides and if you want to give margin to any specific side, you can use (**margin-top, margin-bottom, margin-right or margin left**.)

```html
<div style="margin: 100px">This div has 100px margin.</div>

<div>This is initial div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily try it out.

Create a basic and minimal HTML page and check what's going on. The information in your question is a bit scarce, but take for example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #div1 {background-color: red;}
    #div2 {background-color: green;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="div1" style="">DIV 1</div>
  <div id="div2">DIV 2</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You will end up with two coloured bars just on top of each other.

If you now change `style=""` in line 11 to `style="margin: 100px;"` you will see what changed. 100 Pixel of space to the top, left, bottom and right of the 1st `div`.

But as your question is lacking details, e.g. on how both DIVs are defined, if margin should be `px`, or `em` or such, this answer is basically only guessing.